# How to work with nested loop in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Recently I am working with nest for loop but one loop work and another not working suppose I have 2 for loop.

For example

```
$data           =DB::table('data')->get();
$job            =DB::table('job')->get();
$recruiter      =DB::table('recruiter')->get();
$admin          =DB::table('commission')->get();

for($i=0;i<count($job);i++){
    if(!$job->isEmpty()){
        for($j=0;j<count($job);j++){
            if( $data[$i]->job_id == $admin[$j]->job_id )
                $job[$i]=$data[$i];
        } 
        //if checking complete then skip $i or increment it (less than count($job)) or skip 
        //this index $i and continue with outer loop mean i++
    }
}
```

I had done lots of research but haven't found any solution with this kind of problem

Answer (score 0):

You have missed the `$` in `i` and `j`

```
$data      = DB::table('data')->get();
$job       = DB::table('job')->get();
$recruiter = DB::table('recruiter')->get();
$admin     = DB::table('commission')->get();

for($i=0; $i < count( $job ); $i++){
    if($job->isEmpty()){
        continue;
    }

    for($j=0; $j < count( $job ); $j++){
        if( $data[$i]->job_id == $admin[$j]->job_id ){
            $job[$i]=$data[$i];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i had updated my question please help me i havent getting how i can achieve this

Comment: can you post following var's data `$data` `$job` `$admin`

Comment: Code seems fine, Need to see the data.